# Icon Hover Text Effect

Tags: css, hover, icons

How to make a better effects in this social hover effects. Any Idea?

[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/6whobL3c/)

for example like this: http://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/demo-travel.php

Comment: Better in what way? What exactly is the issue you want to solve?

Comment: when it shows the text I want like "linear or anything" effects

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6whobL3c/

Comment: Please add the relevant "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" code to your question. Don't try and circumvent the rules by pretending your link is code: it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use css transition on width/height, you have to use static values in pixel for exemple (not `auto`).

Here is what it should look like :

```
.social li a {
    width: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    background:transparent;
    transition: width .5s, background .5s;
    padding:5px;
}
.social li.rss a {
    color: #F88F16;
}
.social li.facebook a {
    color: #3B5998;
}
.social li.twitter a {
    color: #3CF;
}
.social li.googleplus a {
    color: #BD3518;
}
.social li.facebook:hover a {
    width: 115px;
    background:#999;
}
.social li.twitter:hover a {
    width: 80px;
    background:#999;
}
.social li.googleplus:hover a {
    width: 105px;
    background:#999;
}
```

> [Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xu3fdk0p/)

P.S.: I cleared your CSS a bit ;)